# How do I create a CKEditor plug-in to support dragging and dropping within an editor instance?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

I was surprised to find that dragging and dropping text or images within a CKEditor editor instance doesn't trigger CKEditor's "change" event. I came up with a stop-gap solution, which was to have code triggered by the "dragend" event. However, I'd like to have something in a CKEditor plug-in, so that in all of my apps that use CKEditor I could include the plug-in in the configuration, rather than have to add a separate block of code in each app. Basically, I'm wondering whether there's a way add another event to what CKEditor considers a change -- without modifying core CKEditor code.

FWIW, here's my code, which is basically the same as my code for handling the "change" event, except with the "change" event I get data from e.sender.getData():

```
$('.content').on('dragend', '.ckeditor', function(e) {
    var editor = $(e.currentTarget).ckeditorGet();
    var data = editor.getData();
    ...
    //if the new data is different from the stored data, save it
});
```

Comment: So what is the question? How to create a plugin?

Comment: No, I know how to create a plug-in. My question is: How do I create a plug-in to support dragging and dropping within an editor instance?

Answer (score 0):

Not an exact answer, but [check ticket 11437](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/11437) targeted into upcoming 4.5 release. In short, d&d is a complex topic and we're working on it right now.

Comment: Cool. Thanks very much. I'd rather *not* have to write a plug-in ;-) I look forward to 4.5.